# How to add <li> tag into hyperlink helper

Tags: php, html, cakephp

As per title above, I am currently facing the problem while adding a nested `<li></li>` tag to the hyperlink html helper.  My code is as follows...

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->tag('li', 'home'), '/home', array('target' => '_blank'));
```

It printed `<li>Home</li>` on the page... May I know how can I make the `<li></li>` as html instead of showing in text form?

Comment: It's hard to say why it did that with just the code that you provided in your question. Please add the actual code which creates the tags.. i.e.: the tag method.

Comment: @DeviantSeev The code he provided does just what he described. The link method escapes HTML tags by default.

Comment: @Juhana - I should learn to read the title of the post as well as the content... missed the hyperlink helper part. :)

Comment: One recommendation: if you want to make a valid HTML, you should find an alternative to this. A list item is not valid within a hyperlink.

Answer (score 4):

Add `'escape' => false` to the options (3rd argument)

Comment: Thanks for the solution and its works!

By the way, I found another solution which is 

<a href='<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => '/home'));?>'><li>home</li></a>